# VMTK - Computing centerlines using VMTK installed in conda

Tags: python, image-processing, conda, vtk, itk

I'm following the tutorial available [here](http://www.vmtk.org/tutorials/Centerlines.html) to compute centerlines of a 3D blood vessel geometry. I tried the following for the input vtp file attached [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vmtk-users/xYSWahhrON8). I run the following code, select source and target points.

```
import vmtk
from vmtk import vmtkscripts
from vmtk import pypes


# 1 Mapping of the branches
# 1.1 Data extraction from vmtk
#vmtkCommand = '''vmtkcenterlines -ifile foo.vtp -ofile foo_centerlines.vtp'''

#pype = pypes.PypeRun(vmtkCommand)
vmtkCommand = '''vmtksurfacereader -ifile foo.vtp
                 --pipe vmtkcenterlines
                 --pipe vmtkrenderer/
                 --pipe vmtksurfaceviewer -opacity 0.25
                 --pipe vmtksurfaceviewer -i @vmtkcenterlines.o -array MaximumInscribedSphereRadius'''
pype = pypes.PypeRun(vmtkCommand)
```

However, I get the following error

```
    raise RuntimeError(errorMessage)
RuntimeError: No module named 'vmtk.'
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this error will be really helpful. I'd like to view the centerline of the geometry in the file attached [here](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/foo.vtp).

Comment: Is this windows or unix? Also from notebook or in a script?

Comment: @cel This is in windows. It's a script

Comment: Please include the steps you followed/operations you performed in the post itself, so as to keep it as self-contained as possible.

Comment: This problem is resolved now. Thanks